# Link-local Multicast over QUdpSocket on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, udp, ipv6, multicast

I am trying to send a UDP telegram using link-local multicast. I am using Qt which offers the QUdpSocket. I was able to do this on Linux but am not able to get the code working on Windows.

My first code looked like this:

```
udp.writeDatagram(QByteArray("hello world"), QHostAddress("FF02::1"), 4321);
```

It works on Linux but not on Windows. I even tried running the application with admin privileges. `writeDatagram()` returns the size of the telegram on both systems.

The only advice I found was sending the telegram on a specific network interface. My code for this approach:

```
foreach(const QHostAddress& address, QNetworkInterface::allAddresses()) {
    udp.bind(address, 0);

    if(address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv6Protocol) {
        udp.writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress("FF02::1"), 4321);
    }

    udp.close();
}
```

The code again sends the telegram on Linux but not on Windows. `allAddresses()` returns IPv6 link-local addresses on both operating systems.

`QUdpSocket::joinMulticastGroup()` did nothing as well (as expected because it only concerns receiving).

I use Wireshark (on the sending machine and another machine in the network) to check whether the telegrams are sent. To check whether the network code works at all I added a IPv4 Broadcast which works on Windows with both solutions. I know my Windows supports IPv6 because it has a link-local address. The Windows firewall was disabled during the tests and I have no other firewall installed on the test system. The complete test code can be found [here in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/thammi/a062aff125ac25150f1c).

Why does Windows refuse to send the telegram? Is my code missing something or is there a Bug in Qt? Did anyone get this to work? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach was correct. I had to `open()` the sockets again after `close()`ing them. I guess I thought this was done in `bind()` because the socket was open after the object is created ...

Working code:

```
foreach(const QHostAddress& address, QNetworkInterface::allAddresses()) {
    if(address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv6Protocol) {
        _udp.bind(address, 0);
        _udp.writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress("FF02::1"), DISCO_PORT);

        _udp.close();
        _udp.open(QUdpSocket::ReadWrite);
    }

}
```